# Getting error while running Jest test case in Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular-unit-test, angular-jest

I created an Angular application, uninstalled Jasmine and Karma and installed Jest. I have done all the steps correctly.
Whenever I run the jest tests it gives me an error: "error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'files'".
I am unable to figure out the issue.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: That error would mean that your files property is in the wrong place but it is missing in your config. Try to add a files property to include actual files